How do I add grounding to my old 220V electrical wiring?
I have a 220V circuit that utilizes NM-B #6 cable.
There is no grounding conductor. I want to utilize the circuit for an EV charger.
Ampacity is correct for the load and distance I need a ground wire.
How can I add this? Add a #6 THHN wire all the way back to the panel? I don't think there are any other circuits nearby with similar size cable.

NM-B 6 AWG is good for up to 55A. A 10 AWG copper wire is sufficient for up to 60A, so the starting point is 10 AWG, not 6 AWG. If you have a 30A grounded circuit (e.g., water heater or clothes dryer) then that should also have a 10 AWG ground wire and you can connect this wire to that circuit's ground wire. If not then you have to run a 10 AWG bare or green wire back to the panel.

Thank you. I do have a dryer nearby. Will check to see if it has a ground wire. If not, I guess I'll run a ground wire to both just to make them a little safer.

If you have a dryer with a 3 wire plug/receptacle then when adding ground or making use of an existing ground (often sitting in the box unused) it is extremely important to switch to a 14-30 plug/receptacle and wire dryer correctly.

First, study the ends of the NM carefully. From time to time we see examples where asshats cut off wires they don't understand rather than simply leaving them alone and capping them. It may be there down near the end of the sheath. If you can get a few inches in from the wall, you might be able to get enough length to use it. Or relocate the box farther up the wire.
But you have several options.
EV's do not use neutral. Some people like 14-50 sockets, but they're not a good choice for home charging - they're intended for travel. So if your cable has a neutral wire, you can permanently re-mark the white wire as a ground by removing the accessible insulation.  That was easy! Now you either hard-wire a wall unit, or use a NEMA 6-30 or 6-50 socket - remember a socket requires a GFCI breaker.  I like hard-wiring myself. Due to constant burn-ups with sockets, I recommend derating a socket to 24 amps. Did I mention I like hard-wiring :)
Or, retrofit ground per NEC 250.130(C) but here's the problem.  You can't retrofit a ground to a new installation.  You are expected to run the correct cable at installation time.   What you can do is retrofit ground to the original location to serve an appliance there.  And then some time later, extend 4-wire from there to your new location.  Code is not particular as to how long.
The retrofit ground rules say you need to run a ground appropriately sized for the circuit (21-60A circuits get #10 ground) to any junction box or the GEC which is #10 or larger back to the panel. Water heater, honest 4-wire dryer circuit, etc.   The GEC is the bare wire running from the panel to your ground rods - you can't cut it, but you can clamp it with a "split-bolt".
